# Debugging in casperJS fails with reference error

Tags: debugging, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to debug casperJS script in chrome browser.I followed [these](https://drupalize.me/blog/201410/using-remote-debugger-casperjs-and-phantomjs) steps.But,I encounter the following error in Console.

[image]

Any thoughts??

I using CasperJS 1.1 and phantomJS 1.9.2